# Unable to Install Ambari as a cluster

Tags: hadoop, ambari

[image]I am trying to configure ambari on single node. I am at confirm hosts phase. Its is showing installing from more than 30 minutes. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit on virtual box(RAM = 4GB). Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't take 30 minutes to register a single host. If you click the `Installing` link under the status column it will drill down into the log of what registration is doing. This may provide more details on what's going wrong with the registration process.